# How to use quotes in Dockerfile CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following in my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/wait-for", "wordpress:9000", "--"]
CMD nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Which results in:

```
nginx_1      | Attempting...
nginx_1      | Command: /bin/sh -c nginx -g "daemon off;"
nginx_1      | Attempting to execute command:
nginx_1      | /bin/sh -c nginx -g "daemon off;"
ayurved_nginx_1 exited with code 0
```

I'm guessing the issues is the quotes...

How can I make it execute `/bin/wait-for wordpress:9000 -- nginx -g "daemon off;"`?

Comment: What if you use the JSON form of `CMD`?  `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "\"daemon off;\""]`

Comment: Doesn't work either

Comment: This should work i guess `CMD ["nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]`

Comment: To explain what's happening: `/bin/sh -c nginx -g "daemon off;"` is running `nginx` as a script with `-g` in `$0` and `daemon off` in `$1`. But the script `nginx` doesn't look at either `$0` *or* `$1`.

Comment: The best option is *not to have* the `/bin/sh -c` at all. If you didn't have a shell, the rest of your argv would be correct exactly as it already is.

Comment: I have no idea where it's getting `/bin/sh -c` from

Comment: Could you provide a proper [mcve] so I could run the container myself? Could probably figure it out from there.

Comment: (mind you, one could come up with something that'll work right when appended to `sh -c` -- a simple do-nothing shim that passes the rest of the argv through might look like `[ "exec -a \"$0\" \"$@\"", "nginx", "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]`, but it's silly to have it there).

Comment: (huh -- apparently `exec -a` is a bashism, so might need to make that `[ "exec \"$@\"", "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]` -- means you give up control of `$0`, but so be it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMD doesn't run after ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447913/cmd-doesnt-run-after-entrypoint-in-dockerfile)

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem when using `CMD` in the exec form, aka JSON array.

The TL;DR is that there seems to be a fallback mechanism that introduces `/bin/sh` when the CMD items cannot be parsed correctly.

I could not find the exact rules but I have examples:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["reflex"]
CMD ["-r", ".go$"]

$ docker inspect --format '{{.Config.Cmd}}' inventories_service_dev_1 
[-r .go$]
```

```
ENTRYPOINT ["reflex"]
CMD ["-r", "\.go$"]

$ docker inspect --format '{{.Config.Cmd}}' inventories_service_dev_1 
[/bin/sh -c ["-r", "\.go$"]]
```

Notice that `\` in above.