# How do I specify run arguments for a base image in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am defining an image in a Dockerfile which has another image as its parent:

```
FROM parent_org/parent:1.0.0
...
```

The parent image's documentation mentions an argument (`special-arg`) that can be passed when running an instance of the container:

```
docker run parent_org/parent:1.0.0 --special-arg
```

How can I enable `special-arg` in my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** you could use the `CMD` directive by doing something like this:

```
FROM parent_org/parent:1.0.0
CMD ["--special-arg"]
```

however note that passing extra flags to `docker run` as below would **overwrite** `--special-arg` (as `CMD` is intended to specify *default* arguments):

```
docker build -t child_org/child .
docker run child_org/child  # would imply --special-arg

docker run child_org/child --other-arg  # "--other-arg" replaces "--special-arg"
```

If this is not what you'd like to obtain, you should redefine the `ENTRYPOINT` as suggested below.

### The CMD and ENTRYPOINT directives

To have more insight on `CMD` as well as on `ENTRYPOINT`, you can take a look at the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJmi9.png) involved in this other SO answer: [CMD doesn't run after ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447984/9164010).

In your case, you could redefine the `ENTRYPOINT` in your `child` image (and if need be, the default `CMD`) by adapting `child_org/child/Dockerfile` w.r.t. what was defined in the `parent` Dockerfile.

> Assuming the `parent_org/parent/Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM debian:stable  # for example

WORKDIR /usr/src/foo
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod a+x entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["--default-arg"]
```

> You could write a `child_org/child/Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM parent_org/parent:1.0.0
RUN […]

# Redefine the ENTRYPOINT so the --special-arg flag is always passed
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh", "--special-arg"]

# If need be, redefine the list of default arguments,
# as setting ENTRYPOINT resets CMD to an empty value:
CMD ["--default-arg"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This baffled me at first, too...  Run them using the `command:` declaration...  A command and an Entrypoint are two different things...  The entrypoint runs whatever script/execution call your service needs to initialize and start. That entrypoint script then usually runs logic to append whatever you pass in from the `command:` declaration as further arguments to alter the behavior of the service.

Comment: If you're not getting the outcome you want, you may have to glance at the entrypoint script to ensure that you understand how it kicks off the service.