# DockerFile CMD won't run Python script

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have been successful building an image for a simple python script that is part of the working directory as follows:

[image]

My `DockerFile` looks as below:

```
# Using Python runtime 3.10
FROM python:3.10

# Set the working directory of the container
WORKDIR /src

# Copy the project directory to the container
COPY . /src/

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Command to run the application
CMD [ "python", "./anonymizer/app/main.py" ]
```

I then build the image successfully -

```
PS C:\Python Test> docker build -t anonymizer -f DockerFile .
```

[image]

And when I run the image interactively -

```
PS C:\Python Test> docker run -it anonymizer /bin/bash
```

It seems to have run successfully too

[image]

However, the python script didn't seem to have run as the files the script were meant to create never got written into the `data/*` folders as below. On the contrary, when I run the same script as defined in `CMD` variable of `DockerFile` from the container, the files do get created as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Why isn't the CMD running the Python script?

Comment: At first sight: just remove the `/bin/bash` argument in CLI. This argument replaces the `CMD` default program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify run arguments for a base image in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634908/how-do-i-specify-run-arguments-for-a-base-image-in-a-dockerfile)

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39408777/9164010)

Comment: (Reminder: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing the last parameter to `docker run`, the `/bin/bash`, you're replacing whatever was set in the Dockerfile's `CMD` statement, and executing the passed command instead.

In your case, the script is not executing because you're attaching youself to a Bash terminal, and overwriting the Python command.

Try running the container in detached mode, and then checking the logs:

```bash
docker run -d --name anonymizer anonymizer
docker logs anonymizer
```

If the Python script is some kind of service or process, you can also attach your shell to a **running** container (if it's a one-off script, the container will be stopped by the time you try to attach):

```bash
docker exec -it anonymizer bash
```