# CMD does not run if used after ENTRYPOINT

Tags: bash, docker, apache-kafka, dockerfile, apache-kafka-connect

I have the following docker file

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.3.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java

# JDBC-MariaDB
RUN wget -nv -P /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/ https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/java/connector-java-2.4.4/mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar

# SNMP Source
RUN wget -nv -P /tmp/ https://github.com/name/kafka-connect-snmp/releases/download/0.0.1.11/kafka-connect-snmp-0.0.1.11.tar.gz
RUN mkdir /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp && tar -xf /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp-0.0.1.11.tar.gz -C /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp/
RUN mv /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp/usr/share/kafka-connect/kafka-connect-snmp /usr/share/java/

COPY plugins-config.sh /usr/share/kafka-connect-script/plugins-config.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/kafka-connect-script/plugins-config.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./etc/confluent/docker/run" ]

CMD ["/usr/share/kafka-connect-script/plugins-config.sh"]
```

And the bash file as this

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#script to configure kafka connect with plugins
# export CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
# export CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083
url=http://$CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:$CONNECT_REST_PORT/connectors
curl_command="curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} $url"
sleep_second=5
sleep_second_counter=0
max_seconds_to_wait=60

echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on localhost" >> log.log
echo "HOST: $CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME , PORT: $CONNECT_REST_PORT" >> log.log
while [[ $(eval $curl_command) -eq 000 && $sleep_second_counter -lt $max_seconds_to_wait ]]
 do 
    echo "In" >> log.log
    echo -e $date " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $(eval $curl_command) " (waiting for 200) $sleep_second_counter" >> log.log
    echo "Going to sleep for $sleep_second seconds" >> log.log
    sleep $sleep_second 
    echo "Finished sleeping" >> log.log
    ((sleep_second_counter+=$sleep_second))
    echo "Finished counter" >> log.log
done
echo "Out" >> log.log
nc -vz $CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME $CONNECT_REST_PORT

/bin/bash
```

Entry point gets called correctly but CMD does not get invoked.

I also try to understand the solution given here [CMD doesn't run after ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447913/cmd-doesnt-run-after-entrypoint-in-dockerfile)

but I did not understand the solution.

If someone could explain a bit more what is wrong here.

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I am trying to have a single docker container image which will start the kafka-connect server (ENTRYPOINT) and then via bash file (CMD) I will configure the plugins. Requirement is that the same sequence of steps gets executed everytime the containers restarts.

Comment: What's the final `/bin/bash` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: I have updated my questions to answer the first question. And the final /bin/bash was added because in some stack overflow answer it was mentioned that if I have to prevent container to keep on running then to add that line at the end of the script, so I am trying various things as you see :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMD` is run after `ENTRYPOINT`, like parameters after a function invokation, **in the same command line**.

In your case you want two different commands running sequentially. Then, you may add them to a `startup_script.sh` whose content is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

./etc/confluent/docker/run & # run in background not to get stuck in here

/usr/share/kafka-connect-script/plugins-config.sh # apply configuration

sleep 100000000 # to avoid the startup script to exit since that would kill the container
```

Comment: (In this approach remember that this shell script is the main container command and will receive signals, and the container will keep running as long as that `sleep` command does.  If the Kafka Connect process dies you will never notice.)

Comment: So I am trying to avoid sleep, so what i did instead 

#!/bin/bash

./usr/share/kafka-connect-script/plugins-config.sh &
./etc/confluent/docker/run

But now the pluging-config.sh is not running again

Comment: if login to the container and run the same entrypoint.sh script from command line then it works, but does not work when called by Docker, does anyone know why?

Comment: @DavidMaze I agree. But you can monitor kafka health with a simple `nc` in a `while` alongside `sleep 60`, for instance.

Comment: @SomeGuyWhoCodes does your first script exits? If not, then the entrypoint you run after will not run.

Comment: I call plugins-config.sh in background and then kafka run script is called which waits then. so plugin-configs.sh is not a blocking call. But in my case the plugins-config.sh is not called

Comment: ok the script works, I was just looking at wrong place :). Thanks