# docker run fails to run shell script (file not found) although the shell script was added successfully with docker build

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

I am using a private docker hub repository `https://hub.docker.com/u/privaterepoexample/`, after which I have built my docker image using the commands below:

```
docker login
docker build -t privaterepoexample/sre:local .
docker tag 85cf9475bc1c privaterepoexample/sre
docker push privaterepoexample/sre
```

The output of docker build which shows `login.sh` added to container:

```
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 85 MiB in 57 packages
Removing intermediate container 12fd67450dfc
 ---> e9ca0b9e4ac4
Step 5/7 : WORKDIR /opt
---> Running in ce881ede94aa
Removing intermediate container ce881ede94aa
---> 2335b4f522ac
Step 6/7 : ADD login.sh /opt
---> 2aabf1712153
Step 7/7 : CMD ["chmod 755 login.sh  && ./login.sh"]
 ---> Running in 8ec824d4e561
Removing intermediate container 8ec824d4e561
 ---> c97a4ad61578
Successfully built c97a4ad61578
Successfully tagged privaterepoexample/sre:local
```

The Dockerfile below is built successfully and login.sh is added successfully:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add curl


WORKDIR /opt


ADD login.sh /opt


CMD ["chmod 755 login.sh  && ./login.sh"]
```

Now here comes with my problem, when I execute `docker run` like below, I get the error:

```
docker run -i privaterepoexample/sre 

 docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"chmod 755 login.sh  && ./login.sh\": stat chmod 755 login.sh  && ./login.sh: 
no such file or directory": unknown.
```

but why does it say no such file? given when I go inside the docker container, I can see the `login.sh` script with the command below:

```
$ docker run -it   
privaterepoexample/sre /bin/sh
/opt # ls
login.sh
/opt # cat login.sh 
#!/bin/sh
# Black Box Tester!
content=$(curl  --location --request POST  
"https://api.platform.abc.com/auth/oauth/token" --header    
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 --header 'Authorization: Basic ' --data-raw 'grant_type=password&
username=event@abc.com&password=fJff'| jq -r 
'.domain_id' )
 if [ $content = abc ]
     then
          echo “Valid Login Token”
else
          echo “invalid url”
fi
/opt # exit
```

Comment: beyond your main question, note that your Dockerfile is suboptimal, because it uses the [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) feature of Docker (namely, you have several `FROM` in your Dockerfile), while it seems this feature is unneeded for your use case. Thus, you may want to remove the first two lines of your Dockerfile and start with `FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine` or even with `FROM alpine` if you don't need a (Java) JRE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the error `no such file or directory` because you are using a so-called [**`CMD` in exec form**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact#cmd) in an unexpected way.

You can fix your `Dockerfile` in several ways, e.g.:

- either use a **`CMD` in shell form**:

  ```
  CMD chmod 755 login.sh && ./login.sh
  ```
- or keep a **`CMD` in exec form** (which is often a good idea), but **ensure the first argument of the JSON array is a program**, not a composite command. You can do this e.g. by running `chmod 755 …` beforehand, at build time:

  ```
  ADD login.sh /opt
  RUN chmod 755 login.sh
  CMD ["./login.sh"]
  ```

For more information on the `CMD` command and its brother command `ENTRYPOINT`, see also this other SO answer: [CMD doesn't run after ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447984/9164010)