# Replacing character in dockerfile variable - error: missing ':' in substitution

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my docker file I have a variable defined for a version number with dots which I want to replace with underscores for a further usage.

```
ARG ABC_VERSION=1.2.3
ARG SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE=/dir_name/abc_${ABC_VERSION//./_}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error.

```
failed to process "/dir_name/abc_${ABC_VERSION//./_}": missing ':' in substitution
```

I need the version number several times within the dockerfile multiple times with the '.' and one time with the '_' and I do not like to define two variables.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

---

Edit: 
One portion of the actual code where I would like to make use of the feature to replace characters is looking like this.

```
ARG EXPAT_VERSION=2.1.0
# ...
RUN wget https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/releases/download/R_${EXPAT_VERSION//./_}/expat-${EXPAT_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar xzf expat-${EXPAT_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && cp -R expat-${EXPAT_VERSION}/lib ./xmp_sdk/third-party/expat \
    && rm -r expat-${EXPAT_VERSION} && rm expat-${EXPAT_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

I saw that something similiar is used in the tensorflow-gpu dockerfiles:

```
ARG CUDA=10.1
#...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    cuda-command-line-tools-${CUDA/./-} #...
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/devel-gpu.Dockerfile

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `${parameter/pattern/string}` syntax is actually a Bash feature (cf. [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)), not a POSIX feature.

According to [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement), the Dockerfile directives only supports:

```
$var
${var}
${var:-word} → if var is not set then word is the result;
${var:+word} → if var is set then word is the result, otherwise the empty string
```

### Workaround 1

So the problem does not have a "direct" solution, but if the variable you would like to substitute will be used, in the end, in some shell command (in a `RUN`, `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` directive), you could just as well keep the initial value as is (with no substitution), then substitute it later on?

I mean for example, the following *Dockerfile:*

```
FROM debian

ARG ABC_VERSION=1.2.3
ENV SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE=/app/${ABC_VERSION}

WORKDIR /app

RUN /bin/bash -c 'touch "${SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE//./_}"'

# RUN touch "${SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE//./_}"
# would raise /bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -hal \"${SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE//./_}\""]
```

As an aside:

- I replaced `ARG SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE` with `ENV SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE` just to be able to use it from `CMD`.
- It can be recalled that `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` directives should rather be written in exec form − `CMD ["…", "…"]` − rather in shell form (see e.g. that question: [CMD doesn't run after ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54447913/9164010)).

### Workaround 2

Or as an alternative workaround, you may want to split your version number in major, minor, patch, to write something like this?

```
ARG MAJOR=1
ARG MINOR=2
ARG PATCH=3
ARG ABC_VERSION=$MAJOR.$MINOR.$PATCH
ARG SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE=/dir_name/abc_${MAJOR}_${MINOR}_${PATCH}
…
```

### A more concise syntax for workaround 1

Following the OP's edit, I guess one concern is the relative verbosity of this line that I mentioned in the "workaround 1":

```
…
RUN /bin/bash -c 'touch "${SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE//./_}"'
```

To alleviate this, Docker allows one to replace the implied shell (by default [`sh`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell)) with Bash, which does support the shell parameter expansion you are interested in. The key point is the following directive that has to be written before the `RUN` command (and which was precisely [part of the Dockerfile the OP mentioned](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2f65c2468d7ff69df9caed94fa4cd6e01d1bd87a/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/devel-gpu.Dockerfile#L38)):

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

Thus, the Dockerfile becomes:

```
…    
ARG ABC_VERSION=1.2.3

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN touch "/dir_name/abc_${ABC_VERSION//./_}" \
  && ls -hal "/dir_name/abc_${ABC_VERSION//./_}"
```

or taking advantage of some **temporary environment variable**:

```
…    
ARG ABC_VERSION=1.2.3

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN export SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE="/dir_name/abc_${ABC_VERSION//./_}" \
  && touch "$SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE" \
  && ls -hal "$SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE"
```

Comment: I added some information regarding the actual code at the end of 
 the post (https://stackoverflow.com/q/61827259/11687201).

Comment: OK; so I added another possible solution in my answer, that may be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explaination why it works in the mentioned tensorflow dockerfile. I only remembered having seen a character substitution in some dockerfile and just overlook the line and comment for the string substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 2024, [dockerfile 1.7.0](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/releases/tag/dockerfile/1.7.0) does include [PR `moby/buildkit` 4427](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/4427/files)

> ### String substitution in variable expansion
>
> - `${variable/pattern/replacement}` replace the first occurrence of `pattern`
>   in `variable` with `replacement`
>
>   ```bash
>   string=foobarbaz echo ${string/ba/fo}  # fooforbaz
>   ```
> - `${variable//pattern/replacement}` replaces all occurrences of `pattern`
>   in `variable` with `replacement`
>
>   ```bash
>   string=foobarbaz echo ${string//ba/fo}  # fooforfoz
>   ```
>
> In all cases, `word` can be any string, including additional environment
> variables.