# Run multiple command after entrypoint with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have been looking to the matrix of interaction of CMD and ENTRYPOINT and I can't found my way to have container running an entrypoint THEN a cmd with multiple commands

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  test:
    image: debian:buster-slim
    entrypoint: [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
    volumes:
      - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    command: [ "echo" ,"toto","&&","echo","tutu" ]
```

where entrypoint.sh is a file containing :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -x
echo tata
exec "$@"
```

"should" print

```
tata
toto
tutu
```

but it's printing

```
tata
toto && echo tutu
```

I found a solution by replacing `[ "echo" ,"toto","&&","echo","tutu" ]` by `"bash -c 'echo toto && echo tutu'"` and then it work.

but I don't get why the first method do not work since the documentation say it will do :

`exec_entry p1_entry /bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMD doesn't run after ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447913/cmd-doesnt-run-after-entrypoint-in-dockerfile)

Comment: No as said I have took to the matrix of interaction of CMD and ENTRYPOINT , it seams that it's not working as espected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is generated by the [`exec`](https://man.cx/exec(1)) command, which synopsis is:

```
exec [command [argument...]]
```

so it will only accept one command with multiple arguments.

#### Solution:

The solution is the one that you pointed out, by using `sh -c ''`:

```
services:
  test:
    image: debian:buster-slim
    entrypoint: [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
    volumes:
      - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    command: ["sh", "-c", "echo toto && echo tutu"]
```

because the final result will satisfy the exec command with one command and multiple arguments

---

On docker side, the official documentation explains the `ENTRYPOINT` vs `CMD` very well with this table:

[docker table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjAJG.png)

[source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact)

If you combine CMD and ENTRYPOINT in the array context the result would be `/entrypoint.sh "echo" "toto" "&&" "echo" "tutu"` because each parameter of the `CMD` will be a parameter for the `ENTRYPOINT`

Here's the output of the example above executed directly in the terminal:

```
# ./entrypoint.sh "echo" "toto" "&&" "echo" "tutu"
+ echo tata
tata
+ exec echo toto '&&' echo tutu
toto && echo tutu
```

And this is the result of the `docker-compose up`

```
# docker-compose up
test_1  | + echo tata
test_1  | tata
test_1  | + exec echo toto '&&' echo tutu
test_1  | toto && echo tutu
root_test_1 exited with code 0
```

As you can see each parameter is passed in the array form so the `'&&'` is parsed as a string (note the single quotes).

#### Note:

The result you expected is this one:

```
# ./entrypoint.sh echo toto && echo tutu
+ echo tata
tata
+ exec echo toto
toto
tutu
```

In this scenario as you see the only parameter passed to the exec is the first `echo toto`.

`echo tutu` is executed in bash terminal after `./entrypoint.sh` script exits.

Obviously if this would be parsed by docker as a separate command it will never be executed because the `ENTRYPOINT` will exit before the `echo tutu` command.